# Inno Setup Passing constant array of string in Unicode installer fails with "Type mismatch" run time error

Tags: unicode, inno-setup, pascalscript

During the conversion of my code to Unicode Inno Setup (5.5.8u) I try to pass a constant array of strings to a function. With Ansi Inno Setup the code works well, but with the Unicode installer a **Type mismatch** run time error occurs. How should I change my code to be able to run it Unicode Inno Setup?

```pascal
  FmtMessage('BlaBla%1', ['abc']);  // works with both inno setup versions
  FmtMessage('BlaBla', []);         // works with both inno setup versions  

  MyFmtMessage(['abc']);     // type mismatch with unicode
  MyFmtMessage([]);                 // type mismatch with unicode

function MyFmtMessage(const Mappings: array of String):String;
var
  Statement : String;
begin
  Statement := 'BlaBla%1';
  FmtMessage(Statement, Mappings);
  Result := Statement;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Open issue [here](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/199)

Comment: Link to your issue for Pascal Script: https://github.com/remobjects/pascalscript/issues/129